# Can Process Builder Create a Task for Lead Object When Leads are Mass Uploaded?

Tags: process-builder

I created a process builder program to create a task when a lead is added to salesforce if it meets specific critera.

The process builder works flawlessly if I manually add a lead or modifiy an existing lead. However, if I try to mass upload a batch of leads the task is not created.

I'm wondering if the process builder does not work with uploading leads or perhaps there is some other setting I need to include within my process builder workflow.

**Process Built**

[image]

**Create Task Trigger Details**
[image: Create Task Trigger Details]

Any insights would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Janine, just to prove to yourself that Process Builder does indeed work for mass imports, try creating and activating a process that _always_ creates a task. If this works, you will know the problem is in your entry criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Process Builder generally executes when importing (as in, uploading records in bulk from any of a variety of sources). However, the Data Import Wizard is different, as it allows you to *not* trigger these rules when importing, so you need to remember to check the box:

[image: Trigger workflow rules and processes unchecked by default]

This box is not checked by default, and must be checked for your Process Builder flows to execute normally. Note that other import mechanisms, such as the Apex Data Loader, do trigger rules and flows by default.

Comment: Worth making a note as it can possibly skip while importing, many thanks.